# How to avoid Nextjs displaying loading state for the whole page when a piece of this page fires a request?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13

I have nextjs page that uses the loading.tsx approach, so when this page load, my loading spinner appears until the whole page is loaded, this is cool. However, in this page I have a popup card that loads by hovering certain element, this popup makes a request to the server to fetch some data, but when the request happens, the whole page gets into the loading state until the request is finished. How can I avoid that?

I tried adding a  around the popup that makes this request, but it did not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the `loading.tsx` component works: it replaces all elements on a page while an asynchronous action is running.

In my opinion, the best approach here is to wrap the Popup component with `Suspense` and provide a different fallback for it, similar to [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/loading-ui-and-streaming#example).

Another, more controlled approach, involves removing `loading.tsx` and adding `Suspense` wrappers to components that use asynchronous actions. You can then create `skeletons` for each component, which improves the user experience but requires more work.

Therefore, if you want to keep the current approach and simply prevent `loading.tsx` from loading while the popup is loading, I recommend following the first method.